# Marklogic: REST query options file location on filesystem

Tags: marklogic

I've been adding a number of search constraints to my Marklogic 6 REST server instance. When using a database module for the REST server, I can see an XML configuration file with the database URL (for example /15946974354972814010/rest-api/options/sgd-identifier.xml).

When I move the modules for the REST server from the database to the filesystem, I can no longer access the sgd-identifier.xml or default.xml files, which does make sense because the database is no longer used. So I thought I would have to copy those files to the folder on my filesystem.

But I cannot get it going. I've been trying stuff to put default.xml in all kinds of folders, including creating a rest-api/options folder. It doesn't get picked up. Is this impossible?

Update: now I understand that it is not possible. Would be nice if Marklogic improves error message and / or documentation because a http 500 error when doing a curl upload to server is not really helpful. I'll accept Dave Cassell's answer, even thought grtjn is also helping out by making it a bit clearer - can't accept both...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](http://docs.marklogic.com/6.0/guide/rest-dev/search#id_28288):

> You can also create custom query options. Before you can use a set of
>   custom query options, you must install them as named options, using
>   /config/query/{name}.

Installing the options through the REST API will put them into your modules database, but that won't work if you've set up to use the filesystem for your modules.

Comment: I tried putting default.xml into {filesystem-root}/config/query/ but it does not work.

Comment: /config/query/{name} is the REST API endpoint you use to install the options, not the place where they end up. Your best bet really is to use a modules database -- that's the intended mode of operation when using the REST API. As grtjn noted, you may be able to fake it by seeing where the REST API puts files in the modules db, then doing that on the filesystem, but I'd encourage you to stick to a modules db.

Answer (score 0):

Dave is right, installing REST api options, extensions, and transforms is not designed to work against app servers running from file-system. If you insist, you will need to mimic the process of installing such artifacts into the proper location. The easiest way to discover how, is to do it against a database first, explore the database to see where and in what shape it ends up in the database, and do the same on the file-system.

It can also be worth considering using a deployment tool that makes it easy to just run against a modules database. Something like [Roxy](http://github.com/marklogic/roxy) for instance..

HTH!